# How do I generate more augmented images than training size in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, data-augmentation

I am aware of data augmentation techniques for images. However, I have a doubt related to how to generate augmented data.

I will share my scenario and code using Keras and Tensorflow however the concept is the same for any library.

Image augmentation technique for the below scenario:

- Random Rotation
- Random Crop

In Keras, we have `ImageDataGenerator` which augments the image while the data is being pulled for training.
For example, if we have 100 images to start with. Then `ImageDataGenerator` will apply the above mention transformations on these images and will output **100** images per epoch (Default `ImageDataGenerator`).

However, if we implement our own `ImageDataGenerator`, we can also implement it to return **100 +  2*100 = 300** images for the training.

> Which of the above-mentioned scenario will be good in general?

Answer (score 3):

You will get 300 unique pictures if you use the same 100 pictures, with augmentation, for three epochs. Every time a picture is loaded, Keras is applying a random transformation.

Look below. This is 16 repeats of a dataset of one image. The same image is never transformed the same way.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import load_sample_image
import numpy as np

imgs = np.stack([load_sample_image('flower.jpg') for i in range(4*4)], axis=0)

data_gen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range = 90,
    width_shift_range = 0.1,
    height_shift_range = 0.1,
    horizontal_flip = True,
    preprocessing_function=lambda x: x[..., np.random.permutation([0, 1, 2])]
)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4))
for index, image in enumerate(next(data_gen.flow(imgs)).astype(int)):
    ax = plt.subplot(4, 4, index + 1)
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I am aware that in 3 epochs I will get 300 images. However, in the scenario I mentioned in the question, option2 will generate 300 images in one epoch itself. So option#1 will generate 100 images and option#2 will generate 300 in one epoch.

Comment: That doesn't change anything. Why don't you just let it run for 3x more epochs? You should let the training continue as long as there is learning, so the number of epochs is meaningless.

Comment: Ok In option#2, the model will see the actual image as well the augmented images. However, in option#1, the model will never see the actual image.

Comment: in tensorflow 2.10 ImageDataGenerator is deprecated. I am currently trying (and struggling a bit ) to use tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory to do this but am not sure of how it works to generate new images. Would someone have an example of how this works?